# MySQL find where values do not exist when comparing two tables

Tags: mysql

I have a series of employee numbers in two tables and I"m trying to find values in a table called HTG_ScheduleRequest that are not found in my images table when I compare columns that contain the employee numbers..

I've issued this command but it is displaying all values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
HTG_ScheduleRequest.AssignedTech
FROM
HTG_ScheduleRequest ,
images
WHERE
HTG_ScheduleRequest.AssignedTech <> images.empno
```

Comment: please provide your table schemes, sample of data and expected result. That would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear, but here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8286ee/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT sr.AssignedTech
FROM HTG_ScheduleRequest sr
LEFT JOIN images i
ON sr.AssignedTech = i.empno
WHERE i.empno IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.AssignedTech
FROM
HTG_ScheduleRequest A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM images B WHERE A.AssignedTech=B.empno);
```

See a [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8286ee/2).